# JQuery REST call does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I try to make an REST-Call with JQuery in JavaScript. The REST-Method returns a simple String.
I tried the following (JQuery is included):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/SecureCloudboxServer/rest/connectionservice/ping',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data){
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR + ' : ' + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

If I execute it in my Browser the alert-Window contains: "[object Object] : error : ".

If I call the URL directly from my Browser I get the expected answer. Does anyone have a clue why it doesn't work?

Comment: What happens when you use `console.log( jqXHR , textStatus , errorThrown )` in Chrome ? What is inside jqXHR ?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
console.log(jqXHR + ' : ' + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
```

alert will not display an object or array

Dont forget to use firebug or something similar with console.log

Comment: If I use console.log I get the following: 
readyState 4, 
responseText undefined,
status 404,
statusText "error"